# Resize UITableViewCell based on content availability in response

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have a self sizing **UITableViewCell** that displays blog posts.
A post consists of **text** and an **image**.  The challenge I now have is that some posts do not contain an image.

How do I size the cell using Auto Layout?  Perhaps should I set the `UIImageView.isHidden = true` instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you said you are using auto resizing cells, following are the steps you should follow:

1) First subclass your `tableview cell` with custom `UITableViewCell` class

2) Take an outlet for UIImageView in above class as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView
```

3) Set the `auto layout` constraints to this image view from storyboard as `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `height` constraint

4) Take outlet for `height constraint` of imageview in the same UITableViewCell class:

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

5) In your `cellForRow` method, check if your data contains image or not. If no image is present, then change the value of height constraint:

```
if myImage == nil {

    if myCustomCell.heightConstraint != nil {

       myCustomCell.heightConstraint.constant = 0
       myCustomCell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This should work as expected. If not, please post the constraints you have applied.

Comment: This worked perfectly @Nilesh Pol.  Thanks very much!